# Can't run PyPi readability package from terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, pypi, readability

I want to use the following PyPI Package on macOS Catalina: https://pypi.org/project/readability/

What the Package does:
Analyses .txt files you have in a certain directory and then gives you a .csv file containing readability values for all the examined .txt files.

My Problem:
You can run this package using one simple command in Terminal. I was able to execute that command before but I forgot to save it and now I am sitting here and don't know what to do.

I am trying to run the following command:

```
$readability [--lang=<en>] --csv /Users/XXXX/Desktop/1980/*.txt >readabilitymeasures.csv
```

But I always get this error:

```
-bash: en: No such file or directory
```

It should be so simple because I managed it before but I reallyd don't know why it doesn't work.

This is the output I get when I try to pip install readability:

`DEPRECATION: 
Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: readability in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (0.3.1)`

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't like square brackets, it treats the contents as a [conditional test](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/what-do-square-brackets-mean-without-the-if-on-the-left). "<" and">" also get interpreted as [redirectors](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html). Your error `bash: en: No such file or directory` comes from bash thinking you want to redirect a file called "en". The square and angle brackets were probably in the package's documentation to indicate that they were variables that could be changed. This should work

```
readability --lang=en --csv /Users/XXXX/Desktop/1980/*.txt > readabilitymeasures.csv
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But now I get a different error: -bash: readability: command not found           I really don't get what is wrong with "readability" @pgcudahy

Comment: Did you install `readability` with `pip install readability`? Is the installation directory in your $PATH? It sounds like you're about to take a trip through the nightmare that is python environments.

Comment: Yes I did it with pip install only thin I noticed is that I got a warning from terminal or pip (idk) that python 2.7 support ended on 01.01.2020. But as far as I red everything should still work. What do you mean with $path?  @pgcudahy

Comment: Yes but it seems like I just had Python 2 - I did pip3 install now and it works! And thank you for your help with the brackets !! @pgcudahy